# How to sort nulls last in a standard page related list

Tags: custom-field

I need to diplay the null value in last when sorting a column in a standard page.
So far I have tries with a formula field using a large value.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this question: [Sort related list with null values last](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12188/sort-related-list-with-null-values-last/12191#12191)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround for you is add new formula field like following and then sort on this formula field.

```
IF(ISNULL(Custom_Object__c), 9999999999999999999, Custom_Object__c)
```

Comment: Do you want to sort a related list on the detail page of the Custom Object record? Or is it the list views?

Comment: Plz ask to @SalesforceAspiration

Comment: @ChetanGupta It is on detail page of Account object.

Comment: It should be IF(ISNULL(Custom_Object__c), 9999999999999999999,Custom_Object__c)